# Rails 4 : how to use UNIX_TIMESTAMP with group YEAR + MONTH

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, grouping

I have the following code

```
Call.group('MONTH(created_at)').count
```

Which returns

```
{9=>57992, 8=>27464, 7=>25175, 6=>26310, 5=>26578, 4=>28090, 3=>33039, 1=>32528}
```

How can I use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` so that the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` value is returned for the year+month (ex. `1356912000000`) instead of the month (ex. `9`) ?

I tried

```
Call.group('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MONTH(created_at))').count
```

But it didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Call.group("UNIX_TIMESTAMP((DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`,'%Y-%m-01 00:00:00')))")
```

Though to keep in mind this would yield different results than:

```
Call.group('MONTH(created_at)').count
```

The first one actually returns what you are asking for, a result grouped by the timestamp of year+month, while the second one does it only for the month i.e. yours groups the results by month number for all years, while the first one does it year by year, if you want month by month for one year you would need to filter for that year specifically.

Sources:

- [MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)
- [MySQL DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)